# Iterate through every node in a XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Hi
I am trying to iterate through every node in a xml, be it the element node, text node or comment. With the below XSL in the very first statement 
prints the complete xml. How do i copy the very first node in $nodes and call the template process-nodes again removing teh first node in my next iteration?

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:call-template name="process-nodes">
<xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="//node()" as="node()*"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="process-nodes">
<xsl:param name="nodes" as="node()*" />
<xsl:copy-of select="$nodes[1]"/>
<xsl:if test="$nodes">
    <xsl:call-template name="process-nodes">
      <xsl:with-param name="nodes"
        select="remove($nodes, 1)" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: I am looking for fixing the issue in this kind of implementation rather than changing the template match to   `<xsl:template match="@* | node()">`  as I need to have some processing which requires this approach.

Thanks.

Comment: @Rachel: This question should be refrase so it focus on the node-set argument, because the stylesheet example is so much anti-XSLT style that people will refactor your stylesheet before answering your question.

Comment: @Rachel: You haven't shown *any* convincing evidence why you cannot use the identity transform or just overrides/derivatives of it. Do try to learn something new, otherwise you are losing a lot as a developer and individual.

Comment: @Dimitre: I do use identity transform for other implementations. In this particular requirement, I want to pass a input param whenever i process a text node. The parameter will be varying after every text node processing. When i use identity transform for text nodes, how do i pass a input param to the template match which keep changing for every text node.

Comment: @Rachel: It would be best if you provide your real problem -- maybe a better solution will be possible. Almost everybody prefers not to be forced to guess what your problem is. The fact that you believe that a particular kind of solution is necessary, doesn't mean that there isn't a better solution. I suspect that there might be an elegant solution to the problem -- you just need to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: @Dimitre: You are right! The problem is: Whenever I process a text node, I need the preceding text length. If I use the predefined function in XSL to find the preceding text length, it is going to be a redundant operation. So after processing each text node, I would want to increment the total length of text nodes and pass it to the next iteration as an input param. Thereafter i would not have to use the function but use the input param as the preceding text length. Am I clear?

Comment: @Rachel, may be it's my language, but the goal is still unclear. You need to sum the string-lengths of all text nodes?

Comment: Yes. When I process any text node, I need the sum of the preceding text nodes. Trying to find how i can achive it without redundantly using the function preceding-text-length.

Comment: @Rachel: Good. I have posted an answer that shows how to perform such tasks in XSLT 2.0 without any explicit recursion. This one uses the generic `foldl()` function to produce the text of the text nodes only up to a certain total-length-limit. At every text node the current accumulated length is passed as part of one of the two patameters. Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear, what are you trying to accomplish, but identity transform does process every node (of all types) and every attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can exclude attributes by removing the `@*` part of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it in the recursive call:

```
<xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position()!=1]" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**From comments of the OP**:

> When I process any text node, I need
>   the sum of the preceding text nodes.
>   Trying to find how i can achive it
>   without redundantly using the function
>   preceding-text-length

**Here comes functional programming and Higher-Order-Functions (HOF) as implemented by the [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net) library**:

Here is a complete code example.This transformation concatenates the text nodes of an XML document only up to a given limit of total length:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:foldl-func="foldl-func"
xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
exclude-result-prefixes="f foldl-func"
>

   <xsl:import href="../f/func-foldl.xsl"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vinitParam" select="100,0,''"/>

      <xsl:value-of select="f:foldl(f:limitedConcat(), $vinitParam, //text() )"/>
    </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="f:limitedConcat">
  <xsl:param name="pAccumResults"/>
  <xsl:param name="pcurrentNode" as="text()"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vLengthLimit" select="$pAccumResults[1]"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vAccumLength" select="$pAccumResults[2]"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
   "for $vNewLength in $vAccumLength+string-length($pcurrentNode),
        $vInLimit in ($vNewLength le $vLengthLimit)
     return
       ($vLengthLimit,
         (if($vInLimit)
          then $vNewLength
          else $vAccumLength) ,

        if($vInLimit)
          then concat($pAccumResults[3], $pcurrentNode)
          else $pAccumResults[3]
        )
   "/>
 </xsl:function>

 <xsl:function name="f:limitedConcat" as="element()">
  <f:limitedConcat/>
 </xsl:function>

 <xsl:template match="f:limitedConcat" mode="f:FXSL">
  <xsl:param name="arg1"/>
  <xsl:param name="arg2"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="f:limitedConcat($arg1,$arg2)"/>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<booklist>
   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

   <book>
      <title>Angela's Ashes</title>
      <author>Frank McCourt</author>
      <publisher>HarperCollins</publisher>
      <isbn>0 00 649840 X</isbn>
      <price>6.99</price>
      <sales>235</sales>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Sword of Honour</title>
      <author>Evelyn Waugh</author>
      <publisher>Penguin Books</publisher>
      <isbn>0 14 018967 X</isbn>
      <price>12.99</price>
      <sales>12</sales>
   </book>

</booklist>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
100 100 Angela's AshesFrank McCourtHarperCollins0 00 649840 X6.99235Sword of HonourEvelyn WaughPenguin Books
```

**Explanation**:

This is similar to:

```
f:foldl(f:add(), 0, 1 to 10)
```

the above expression calculates the sum of the numbers from 1 to 10:

- The function `f:add()` is passed as the first parameter to `f:foldl()`.
- The second parameter is the initial accumulated value -- 0.
- The third parameter is the sequence of items to be processed.

The foldl function takes the current accumulated value and the current head of the sequence (the head of the 3rd argument) and applies the `f:add()` function on them. The result becomes the new accumulated value and foldl() calls itself recursively with the same 1st argument, the new accumulated value and the tail of the sequence.

In the solution above the accumulated value is a tripple consisting of the text-length-limit, the accumulated length and the accumulated string concatenation.

Instead of `f:add()` we use `f:limitedConcat()`, which adds both the string length and also concatenates the current text node's value if the total value will not exceed the specified total-text-limit.

Comment: @Rachel: You are welcome. I will be glad to help you in adapting this to your purposes. Please, consider up-voting/accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a contradiction implicit in your question. You say:

> With the below XSL in the very first statement prints the complete xml.

which implies that you aren't happy that processing the first node copies the entire XML.

Then you say:

> How do i copy the very first node in $nodes

but the first node in $nodes is the root of the tree, and copying it will copy the entire XML.

So the question is really: what output do you want to produce? Can you describe the transformation you want to perform? Because we can't really answer the question starting from your incorrect code.